# Dynamic Excel Power Query

Tags: excel, powerpivot, powerquery

I have a table in an Excel Workbook named "ParameterTable".  In this table I store parameters that I want to pass to SQL queries executed via Excel Power Query.

To pull these parameters from the workbook, I use a function called "fnGetParameter".  The function code looks like this:

```
let //Function name and parameters
fnGetParameter = (ParameterName as text, ColumnNum as text) =>
let

//Assign Table and Column for function
ParamSource = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="ParameterTable"]}[Content],
ParamRow = Table.SelectRows(ParamSource, each ([Parameter Name] = ParameterName)),

//Assign value for return
Value=

if Table.IsEmpty(ParamRow)=true
    then null
else if ColumnNum = "1"
    then Record.Field(ParamRow{0},"Value1")
else if ColumnNum = "2"
    then Record.Field(ParamRow{0},"Value2")
else null

in

Value

in
    fnGetParameter
```

So, basically I can specify a parameter name and a column number and this function will pass it when called in other Power Query queries.

An example call would look like:

```
let
PassedParameter = Expression.Evaluate("fnGetParameter{"ParamLabel","1"}",[fnGetParameter=fnGetParameter]),
Source = Sql.Database("ServerName", "Databasename", [Query="select * from table where Column1 = " PassedParameter" ])
in Source
```

My problem arises in that I want to save the SQL query into a text file and connect to that text file rather than store the query in Excel.  For some reason, when Power Query tries to call the fnGetParameter function (which is a user defined function in the workbook), the SQL query can't seem to "see" the PQ UDF.

My main reason for doing this (saving SQL query PQs to a text file) is it makes editing the query easier in a text file and it avoids having to change the query multiple times if other workbooks use similar queries.

Thoughts?

Comment: https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2014/02/04/loading-power-query-m-code-from-text-files/ here is an example of loading power query from text file.

Comment: I think you've missed the whole point of Power Query, which is that you click around the UI to effortlessly transform data, while it's engine dynamically generates the SQL for you.  For this scenario you would probably be better off coding the whole solution directly in VBA,  .NET or similar.